# Python: Classes: Need to turn my list into a generator

Tags: python, function, class, generator

I have tried implementing the "yield" into the code so it would return a generator, but it's returning:

<**generator object PText.possible at 0x000001C9F4E03DB0**>

I essentially need to use a generator because the txt file that I am using is VERY long and creating the list takes a while and is slow, so I need to implement a generator somehow to make it so that it won't take as much time.

I wrote all the code using return statements and tried plugging in yield instead but it's not working. Am I missing something? I believe there's two instances in the code where a generator is needed but I can't figure it out.

This is one continuous code and I labelled where I used yield:

```
WORD_LIST_FILE = 'English_words_by_usage_rank.txt'
# this is just a file with a list of words

class PText(object):
    keyMap = {'1': "'-", '2': 'abc', '3': 'def',
              '4': 'ghi', '5': 'jkl', '6': 'mno',
              '7': 'pqrs', '8': 'tuv', '9': 'wxyz'}
    wordsByPrefix = None
    rankByWord = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.keys = []

    def add(self, keys_typed):
        """ Append a new key press (or a sequence of them) onto current word.
        keyPress -- '2', '3', ..., '9' from telephone keypad.
        >>> pt= Ptext()
        >>> pt.add('345')
        >>> pt.keys
        ['3', '4', '5']
        """
        for key in  keys_typed:
            if key in PText.keyMap:
                self.keys.append(key)

    def backspace(self):
        """Remove last key press from current word (backspace)."""
        if len(self.keys) > 0:
            self.keys.pop()

    def match(self, word):
        """See if word might be what the phone user is trying to type."""
        if len(word) < len(self.keys):
            return False
        for i in range(len(self.keys)):
            letter = word[i]
            keystroke = self.keys[i]
            ok_letters = PText.keyMap[keystroke]
            if letter not in ok_letters:
                return False
        # if all the keys matched the corrresponding letters in word
        return True
```

I used a yield in this part:

```
    def possiblePrefixes(self):
        """ Generate a list of all 3-char prefixes that can be gernerated
        from the beginning key presses.
        """
        if len(self.keys) < 3:
            raise ValueError("not enough keys for prefixes")
        ret = []
        kmap = PText.keyMap
        for c1 in kmap[self.keys[0]]:
            for c2 in kmap[self.keys[1]]:
                for c3 in kmap[self.keys[2]]:
                    ret.append(c1 + c2 + c3)
        yield ret

    def _performCaching(self):
        """Read word list into data structures that we will use:

        wordsByPrefix -- a dictionary that contains a list of words in rank
                         order for each 3-letter prefix encountered in the
                         word list

        rankByWord -- a dictionary that maps each word to its rank

        If these are already filled in (not None), then return immediately.

        Reads the word list file, WORD_LIST_FILE, which has all possible
        English words (that we will consider) listed in rank order.
        """
        if PText.wordsByPrefix is not None:
            return
        wbp = {}
        rbw = {}
        rank = 1
        file = open(WORD_LIST_FILE, 'r')
        for word in file:
            if word[-1:] == '\n':
                word = word[:-1]
            #print("'" + word + "'")
            if len(word) >= 3:
                prefix = word[:3].lower()
                if prefix in wbp:
                    wbp[prefix].append(word)
                else:
                    wbp[prefix] = [word]
                rbw[word] = rank
                rank += 1
        file.close()

        PText.wordsByPrefix = wbp
        PText.rankByWord = rbw
```

Another yield here:

```
    def possible(self):
        """Returns a list of possible words given the current key sequence.
        Assumes at least 3 keystrokes have been entered (raises ValueError
        otherwise). Returned in rank order.
        """
        self._performCaching()
        if len(self.keys) < 3:
            raise ValueError('Too few keys for predicting word')
        wbp = PText.wordsByPrefix
        ret = []
        for prefix in self.possiblePrefixes():
            if prefix in wbp:
                wordList = wbp[prefix]
                for word in wordList:
                    if self.match(word):
                        ret.append(word)
        ret1 = []
        [ret1.append(item) for item in ret if item not in ret1]
        yield ret1


    def best(self):
        """Return the most likely English word for the current key sequence.
        Assumes at least 3 keystrokes have been entered (raises ValueError
        otherwise). If there a no words that match the current key sequence,
        ValueError is raised.
        """
        rank = 1
        highest = 1
        ranking = {}
        for prefix in self.possible():
            ranking[prefix] = rank
            rank += 1
        for vals in ranking.values():
            if vals == highest:
                highest = vals
        bests = ([k for k,v in ranking.items() if v == highest])
        for i in bests:
            answer = i
        return i
```

Comment: You wanted a generator, and you got a generator. What's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: If you print out a generator, what you get is something that looks like `<generator blah blah at 0x12345678>`. If you were expecting to get something that looks like a list of values… well, think about it: the only way it could do that is if it consumed the generator immediately, after which it would no longer be useful.

Comment: If you're just trying to check the generator on a small test case, for debugging purposes, the simplest thing to do is `thing = list(thing)`. Then you can print out `thing` (and continue to use it afterward, too). Obviously don't put this in your _real_ code, but for debugging it's very often helpful to convert (small) generators to lists like this.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding and use of generators is incorrect.  Here's a simplified example of what you are currently trying to do:

```
def possiblePrefixes():
    ret = []
    keys = ['abc','def','ghi']
    for c1 in keys[0]:
        for c2 in keys[1]:
            for c3 in keys[2]:
                ret.append(c1 + c2 + c3)
    yield ret

print(possiblePrefixes())
```

Output:

```
<generator object possiblePrefixes at 0x000001DCFFCE99E8>
```

That's normally what you get when you print the return value of a generator.  What you do with a generator is *iterate* over it, but the logic is flawed.  You've generated all the answers in a list, and yield one big list.  That defeats the purpose of a generator:

```
for p in possiblePrefixes():
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
['adg', 'adh', 'adi', 'aeg', 'aeh', 'aei', 'afg', 'afh', 'afi', 'bdg', 'bdh', 'bdi', 'beg', 'beh', 'bei', 'bfg', 'bfh', 'bfi', 'cdg', 'cdh', 'cdi', 'ceg', 'ceh', 'cei', 'cfg', 'cfh', 'cfi']
```

A generator should yield one value at a time.  It doesn't generate all the values up front:

```
def possiblePrefixesFixed():
    ret = []
    keys = ['abc','def','ghi']
    for c1 in keys[0]:
        for c2 in keys[1]:
            for c3 in keys[2]:
                yield c1 + c2 + c3

print(possiblePrefixesFixed())

for p in possiblePrefixesFixed():
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
<generator object possiblePrefixesFixed at 0x000001DCFFCE99E8>
adg
adh
adi
aeg
aeh
aei
afg
afh
afi
bdg
bdh
bdi
beg
beh
bei
bfg
bfh
bfi
cdg
cdh
cdi
ceg
ceh
cei
cfg
cfh
cfi
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a little bit confused as to how `yield` works.

One example is

```
def square_gen_fun(seq):
    for i in seq:
        yield x
```

I am going to return a generator object. To access the results of this generator, I can iterate over it like so:

```
gen = square_gen_fun(range(5))
for i2 in gen:
     print(i2, end=' ')
```

which will print out `0 1 4 9 16`

What you're doing here

```
ret = []
for c1 in kmap[self.keys[0]]:
    for c2 in kmap[self.keys[1]]:
        for c3 in kmap[self.keys[2]]:
            ret.append(c1 + c2 + c3)
yield ret
```

is wrong. You're are going to return a generator object which has one element, a list or `c1+c2+c3` elements. What you actually want is:

```
for c1 in kmap[self.keys[0]]:
    for c2 in kmap[self.keys[1]]:
        for c3 in kmap[self.keys[2]]:
            yield c1 + c2 + c3
```